# 'grep -l' is not working for a folder with sub folders

Tags: unix, search, grep, ibm-midrange

I am trying to search for file contents. The file is in a directory with sub folders.

The command

```
grep -l 'keyword'
```

is working and is finding all files which are under a folder. If I am searching in a folder with subfolders, I am not getting any results.

Is there any way to search file contents using a directory level search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l 'keyword' {} \;
```

You can also limit the find with the `-name` option and give it a shell regular expression, for example, '*.txt'.

Where '.' is the current folder you're in -- you can also give any directory path instead of '.' to search a given folder.

See: `man find`

Comment: Thanks for the help   find . -type f -exec grep -n 'keyword' {} \; list  the occurances in files.. but file name is not listing..how can list name and occurance like in grep -n .if you can please add that in your answer

Answer (score 2):

This usage `grep` each file under your current directory (including subdirectories).

```
find | xargs grep -l 'keyword'
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

```
find ./folder -type f -exec grep -l 'keyword' {} \;
```

Where `./folder` is the folder you want to search

Comment: Thanks for the help find . -type f -exec grep -n 'keyword' {} \; list the occurances in files.. but file name is not listing..how can list name and occurance like in grep -n .if you can please add that in your answer

Comment: you want `grep -l` not `grep -n`, -n gives you the line number of the match, -l gives you the filename

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
grep -rl 'keyword' *
```