# Locating "undefined" references in a C/C++ Project

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, g++, shared-libraries

I am building a C++ project on my Ubuntu 64bit system using a provided `Makefile`, and this project also provides an API library for developers.

The compilation was successful, no errors at all, but when I try to include in my files the API libraries provided in the "api" folder, then `g++` complains about **undefined references**.

It is not a problem about dependencies (I already built the project succesfully), in fact the missing references are about classes and functions provided by the project, but they are in some specific (sub-)folders (I don't know which ones!), I guess in some **.so files**, and `g++` is not finding them, probably because it does not know they are in those specific subfolders.

It is not the first time this happens when trying to use APIs from **any project**, then I think I am missing something or I am doing something wrong in general when trying to use the libraries provided in a project.

In particular, the main problem is that I don't know how to **tell the compiler where some classes or data structures are declared**, and moreover I don't know how to **locate** them in order to know where they are.

Usually, a workaround I use to avoid this problem is to run `make install`  (as root or using `sudo`) so that libraries and APIs are installed in standard folders (like `/usr/include` or `/usr/lib`) and if I do this thend I can include the API libraries using `#include <library>`, but in this last case it didn't work either, because perhaps some required files containing the not found classes/structures are not properly installed in the right folders in the system.

Another workaround I used sometimes is to try to put all the project files in the same folder instead of using the project folder structure, but clearly this is not good! :-)

But I noticed that several other people **managed to use the APIs**, then apparently they know some way of finding the files containing the "undefined" references and including them in the compilation.

**Then my general question is:** given a "classic" C++ project based on "Makefile" files and with usual folder names like `src`, `lib`, `build`, `bin`, etc., if I want to write C++ files using the libraries provided by the project, but the compiler complains about undefined references, **how can I find the files (.so or .o or .cpp) containing such references?** Is there any tool to find them? And **how can I tell the compiler where they are?** Should I use some command-line option for `g++` or should I use the `#include` macro in some smart way?

PS I also tried to use the `pkc-config` linux tool to get right options to use for compilation and they were available, but the compiler still complains about the undefined references.

**Some more degails about the project i tried:**

For interested people a link to the project is below:
https://github.com/dreal/dreal3

And instructions on how to build it:
http://dreal.github.io/download/

Comment: I typically just CTRL+SHIFT+F and copy+paste the name of the symbol that the compiler complains about which finds me the symbol. Any IDE should have some functionality to search for symbols, but in a pinch [find/grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144501/grep-l-is-not-working-for-a-folder-with-sub-folders#8144580) will do.

Comment: IN my experience this is totally project dependent. You need to grock the project build process to some degree, then search for where the missing piece is, and work backwords to figure out how it should be accessed. find/grep is dirty and brute force, and sometimes the best place to start. In addition to find/grep, check out ack. https://beyondgrep.com/

Comment: ctags will generate a TAGS file that gives the location of the definition for every symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the -rpath linker option - specifically with the "$ORIGIN" argument. That lets you find libraries relative to your executable location so you don't have to install them to the standard locations but just need to put them somewhere known, relative to the executable. That should help you with one piece of the puzzle.

Note: `-Wl,` can be used to pass arguments to the linker via g++.

As for pointing the compiler/linker at a library so it can resolve undefined references by using that library, use the `-l` (that's lowercase L) option to specify the library name and `-L` to specify directories to search for libraries.

As for looking into a library (.so) file to see what symbols are in there, you have a few tools at your disposal: `objdump`, `nm`, `readelf` and `objcopy`.

Comment: Hi Jesper, many thanks! You mean I should use the ld tool manually instead of automatically (via g++)? and when should I use it? When building the project or when compiling my files which use the project libraries? Could you imagine an example of command you would run in a hypothetical project? –

Comment: Using those options through g++ is fine. Check the g++ documentation for the details - you have som pointers for what to look for now.

Comment: Many thanks Jesper, I am going to try in the next hours